# Artifactory system export/import

Tags: import, export, system, artifactory

I'm running an Artifactory Pro 5.8.3 instance and I'm checking that I'm able to restore a full instance backup using system export and import (in another 5.8.3 instance).
I faced several issues that I handled with workarounds described in tickets RTFACT-17067 and RTFACT-15679 but I still have one last issue: access tokens seem to be exported from original instance (at least, they are visible in exported access.bootstrap.json) but not imported in my backup instance. No error appeared in import logs.
Did anyone already have this kind of issue ?
Thanks,

EDIT:
Hi and thanks a lot for all this information, it was very helpful :-).
I've made the tests you suggested and here are the results:

- For case 1, the service_id is identical on both instances and in
  access.bootstrap.json generated from export.
- For case 2, the private key and root certificates are identical on
  both instances.

Answer (score 0):

JFrog access tokens are standard JWT. As such, the token itself is not stored in the DB - only a subset of the Token's metadata that is relevant for the token management is stored in DB, and that metadata (like Token ID, expiry etc.) is (or should be) imported when you import it into a new instance.

However, importing **only** the Token metadata does not mean you'll be able to use your token on the imported instance.

As a standard JWT, the token itself contains the claims (Scope, Audience) that make up the token's "permissions".
When a request is made with such a token, only the token's signature is verified. If the signature is OK, the claims stated within the Token are automatically respected.

So, you're problem will probably be one of the following 2:

1. Your token's audience claim does not include the imported service ID.

When you import an instance, the service ID is supposed to be imported as well. check the instance's service ID using

```
curl -uadmin:password -XGET "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/system/service_id"
```

and check if the ID is part of the token's Audience.

2. Your imported server doesn't have the exported server's trusted key.

Again, this should be included as part of the import. If that is the case, this means the signature verification fails when you use a token in a request. [you can read about it here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/ACC/Access+Tokens#AccessTokens-Cross-InstanceAuthentication)
You can try a simple curl with a token, and check the error that is being returned to verify if that is the case.

HTH